# How to compute the probability with rolling 3 fair dice for some specific condition

Tags: r, statistics, probability

Considering the probability distribution associated with rolling 3 fair dice labelled d1, d2 and d3, I have to calculate the probability of the following:

- a. Compute the probability that the sum of the dice is greater than 12 and less than 18.
- b. Compute the probability that the sum is even.
- c. Compute the probability that the mean is exactly 4.

As referred from another question in stackoverflow, I can solve (a) and (b) as below:

a.

```
mean(dice.sums > 12 & dice.sums < 18) # Assume that, I already calculated the dice.sums
```

b.

```
mean(dice.sums%%2 ==0)
```

Any advice for solving the question (c) assuming that mean equal to the average labels of the dice are already created?

Comment: This question a) provides no evidence of having attempted a solution b) is more suited to a mathematics forum and c) is obviously a homework assignment.

Comment: [Homework questions are ok](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), as long as it's properly presented (of which this does a fairly decent job, including some code/attempts). Tips: If you use `outer` with `+` to get `dice.sums`, (a) and (b) look good. For (c), you already have totals and number of items, so divide to find the mean, then check the condition and take the mean like the others.

Comment: The mean is exactly 4 implies that the sum of the dice is equals to...? Then it's just a matter of using the same approach as parts a and b.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a comparison between the simulated and the actual probabilities for each of the 3 cases (the theoretical probabilities are **55/216**, **108/216** and **25/216** by the *classical definition of probability*, theoretical probabilities are represented as dotted lines):

```
# simulated probs
num.repeat <- 100
num.trials <- 10^3
sim.probs <- vector("list", 3)
for (j in 1:num.repeat) {
  res <- .rowMeans(replicate(num.trials, {
    #dice <- as.integer(runif(3,1,6)) # does not work
    dice <- sample(1:6, 3, replace=TRUE)
    s <- sum(dice)
    p1 <- ((s > 12) && (s < 18))
    p2 <- (s %% 2 == 0)
    p3 <- ((s/3) == 4)
    c(p1, p2, p3)
  }), 3, num.trials)
  for (i in 1:3) {
    sim.probs[[i]] <- c(sim.probs[[i]], res[i])
  }
}
plot(x=0, y=0, xlim=c(1,num.repeat), ylim=c(0,0.6), pch=19, xlab='num.repeat', ylab='prob', main='Simulated vs. Actual Probs')
for (i in 1:3) {
  points(sim.probs[[i]], pch=i, col=i)
}
legend("topright", c('prob1', 'prob2', 'prob3'), pch=1:3, col=1:3)

# theroetical probs
actual.probs <- rep(0,3)
# all points in the sample space
for (d1 in 1:6) 
  for (d2 in 1:6)
    for (d3 in 1:6) {
      s <- d1 + d2 + d3
      actual.probs[1] <- actual.probs[1] + ((s > 12) && (s < 18))
      actual.probs[2] <- actual.probs[2] + ((s %% 2) == 0)
      actual.probs[3] <- actual.probs[3] + ((s / 3) == 4)
    }
actual.probs <- actual.probs / 6^3 # theoretical probs
for (i in 1:3) {
  abline(h=actual.probs[i], lty=2, lwd=2, col=i)  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you read the assignment then the Hint*** states to use subset to select the events and sum P.

subs <- subset(data.frame, data.frame$mean==4)
then colSums(subs)

Answer (score 0):

```
# All possible dice rolls:
dice.sums <- outer(outer(1:6, 1:6, FUN = '+'), 1:6, FUN = '+')

# Probability of a roll greater than 12 and less than 18: 0.2546
prob.12.18 <- mean(dice.sums > 12 & dice.sums < 18)

# Probability of an even roll: 0.5
prob.even <- mean(dice.sums %% 2 == 0)

# Probability of a mean roll value of exactly 4: 0.1157
prob.mean.4 <- mean(dice.sums == 12)
```